# Serialize the Data into JSON

Tags: serialization

Would like to make this solution as a generic solution wherein instead of Person object, GetJSON Method should accept the generic type which is has the DataContract attribute. Can anybody explain how to go about doing it.

Here is the base code

```
namespace TestDataContractJsonSerializer
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Person> persons = new List<Person> { new Person("Person1"), new Person("Person2") };

            var strJSON = from p in persons select GetJSON(p);
            Console.WriteLine("In JSON Format: ");

            foreach (string str in strJSON)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" {0}", str); 
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string GetJSON(Person p)
        {
            if (p != null)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
                dataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, p);
                stream.Position = 0;
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return string.Empty;


        }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {

        public Person(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this in the very basic case. You'd probably need to add some special casing and/or error handling, for instance if the type T is not serializable.

```
    private static string GetJSON<T>(T objToSerialize)
    {
        if (objToSerialize != null)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractJsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());
            dataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, objToSerialize);
            stream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return string.Empty;


    }
```

Comment: Instead of Giving Generic T , i gave object but it started throwing exception. But with Generic T it works fine. Thank You. do you have any idea why it gave exception when object is used instead of "T"